# Is there a service to enter in Monero private view keys to see current balance?

Tags: viewkey, privatekey, view-only

Is there a service where I can just paste my Monero private view key to see the updated balance, even though it doesn't show the spent outputs. Just received is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a service to enter in Monero private view keys to see current balance?

No. You cannot get a balance using a private view key because you can only see incoming transactions with your private view key, not outgoing spends, which would be needed to calculate a balance.